# A challenge to make 1 - 100

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

So this challenge is you have (don't have to) make the numbers 1 - 100 by using  the numbers 1, 3, 4, 6 only once. I'm stuck on how to make 54. Can anyone help me?

P. S. You can use +, -, ÷, x, ! And others you can think of.

Thanks for helping me! I was really stuck on 100.

STOP SAYING THAT I FOUND THIS SOMEWHERE I MADE IT.

Also you can combine numbers like 1 & 3 to 13 or 31

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! 1) This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere, and for such puzzles we require attribution. A link, for example. 2) I've removed your request to make a Google Doc because that's not how this site works. Answers go in answers where they can be seen by all, not just the asker.

Comment: Number formation puzzles must have the allowed operations *very well defined*. Otherwise people will come up with floor, ceiling, square root, nth root, nPk, nCk, gamma, zeta, etc. and it quickly goes out of hand.

Comment: Please stop changing the question you're asking. So far you've asked us to make 51, 54, and 100, all at different times. Either ask for all the numbers or a specific sub-set, then **don't change**.

Comment: Though the site shows only one close reason (which is resolved now I assume), I don't think you addressed my comment above. The allowed operations should be in the form of "this, this, and this are allowed, **and you cannot use anything else**".

Comment: $54 = 6 \times 3 \times (4-1)$

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> $(6+4)^{(3-1)} = 10^2 = 100 $

Comment: Exponentiation isn't explicitly listed as an allowed operation, but I guess it would fall under "And others you can think of."

Answer (score 1):

With the comment "And others you can think of."

> (4+3)!! - 6+1 = 105 - 5 = 100